# UIScrollView with UIView Can't Select Any Subview Items

Tags: ios, swift

I currently have a UIViewController setup like this, and I'm unable to interact with the controls in the contentView.

I'm currently following this concept: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithScrollViews.html

```
class SimpleViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
            let newScrollView = UIScrollView()
                
            newScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            let safeGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
            
            self.view.addSubview(newScrollView)
            newScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
            newScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            newScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            newScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            
            return newScrollView
        }()

        let contentView: UIView = {
            let newView = UIView()
            
            newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            
            scrollView.addSubview(newView)
            
            newView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            newView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            newView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            
            return newView
        }()

        let createBtn: UIButton = {
            let btn = UIButton()

            btn.setTitle("Create", for: UIControl.State.normal)

            btn.backgroundColor = .orange;
            btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

            contentView.addSubview(btn)

            btn.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
            btn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10);
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

            return btn
        }()


        let cancelBtn: UIButton = {
            let btn = UIButton()

            btn.setTitle("Cancel", for: UIControl.State.normal)

            btn.backgroundColor = .red;
            btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

            contentView.addSubview(btn)

            btn.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
            btn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10);
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: createBtn.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            btn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true

            btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.cancelCreateOrder), for: .touchUpInside);

            return btn
        }()
    }
}
```

If I were to add the buttons directly to the scrollView, then I can interact with them. However, with them in the contentView, it's not registering any clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 2 constraints

```
 // contentView should tell scrollView it's width ( setting the leading and trailing isn't enough what matters the width to be inside the scrollView which is still un-known even after hooking the leading & trailing )
newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

And

```
 // contentView should tell scrollView it's height by top & bottom constraints hooking 
btn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: No idea exactly why, but this worked! Thanks.